# How to sort within my aggregated group of duplicates by date

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

This is how my data looks like:

```
    {"_id":{"$oid":"61361d140e9b57aded3f164f"},"FeatureName":"AI Box Kreis (14)","radius":29.85,"x_TCP":-52.7541694301,"y_TCP":-98.7192782699,"z_TCP":-1.4229479066,"w_TCP":179.9808127426,"p_TCP":-0.0080311453,"r_TCP":0.1707167947,"exp1":5,"ExtractionState":"NoGoodContrast","ExtractionQuality":0,"avgBright":21.9513334771,"stdBright":3.3364276129,"RobotPoseName":"Position_1","J1":-8.5,"J2":49.32,"J3":-86.37,"J4":10.74,"J5":-7.33,"J6":170,"J7":0,"EvaluationFilename":"FeatureData_Position_1_Messung 2.fml","MeasurementFilename":"ascii_Position_1_Messung 5.txt","SceneFilename":"Messung 2_sc.png","point_file":"D:\\LRZSync\\Messungen\\Kreis_14_x_-50_y_-100_100_10/3D-Measurements\\Position_1_Messung 2.txt","points":1443,"points_ply":null,"version":"master","user":"niclas","Messreihe":"test","date":{"$date":"2021-09-06T13:52:20.000Z"}}
```

When I'm updating my data I check if I got any duplicates with this kind of code:

```
    issue = collection.aggregate([{'$sort': {'date': 1}},
                              {'$group': {'_id': {'FeatureName': '$FeatureName', 'ExposureTime': '$exp1',
                                                  'Joint1': '$J1', 'Joint2': '$J2', 'Joint3': '$J3',
                                                  'Joint4': '$J4',
                                                  'Joint5': '$J5', 'Joint6': '$J6', 'Joint7': '$J7'},
                                          'unique_ids': {'$addToSet': '$_id'},
                                          'count': {'$sum': 1}}},
                              {'$match': {'count': {'$gt': 1}}}])
        for matches in issue:
            del matches['unique_ids'][0]
            for i in matches['unique_ids']:
                remove.append(i)
```

The '$sort' should sort the duplicates within the groups by date so my unique_ids list has the sorted ObjectIds per duplicate by date. First the 'oldest' ObjectId und last one the 'newest'.
The actual result is that the ObjectIds are unsorted, so the first could be the oldest but doesn't have to be.

Is it possible to sort within the group by date and if so could someone help me with the issue please?

This is my output:

```
    {'_id': {'FeatureName': 'AI Box Kreis (14)', 'ExposureTime': 5, 'Joint1': -8.28, 'Joint2': 37.65, 'Joint3': -77.14, 'Joint4': 4.76, 'Joint5': -16.49, 'Joint6': 175.87, 'Joint7': 0}, 'unique_ids': [ObjectId('6137239fc1397e6a8fb3a965'), ObjectId('61372390f3ba8e37db3f98a9'), ObjectId('613723ac0c8e9387544bf28e')], 'count': 3}
```

The ObjectIds in unique_ids should be sorted by date but they aren't.

Answer (score 0):

```
issue = collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                FeatureName: "$FeatureName",
                ExposureTime: "$exp1",
                Joint1: "$J1",
                Joint2: "$J2",
                Joint3: "$J3",
                Joint4: "$J4",
                Joint5: "$J5",
                Joint6: "$J6",
                Joint7: "$J7",
            },
            unique_ids: { $addToSet: "$_id" },
            count: { $sum: 1 },
        },
    },
    { $match: { count: { $gt: 1 } } },
    { $sort: { date: -1 } },
]);
```

Your `$sort` should be at the end. In your code it is like, you are sorting it first and then grouping it. But its always like you get what the output you want and then accordingly you sort it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but the problem stays the same. The ObjectId in my unique_ids array are still unsorted.

Comment: so sort them as well. `_id : 1`. id of unique_ids